# How do I reset a variable at 12pm every night? swift

Tags: swift, nsdate

I am trying to develop a tracking app that tracks if you do a certain thing every day. Users will be able to press a button to say they did that thing that day. The challenge I am facing is how do I reset a variable that says they've completed that item every night at 12pm. What would be the best approach to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think your approach (ie reset a variable) is right here as, if you intend to run on an iOS device, you can't be certain your app is going to keep alive forever: cf. [*Execution States for Apps* in *The App Life Cycle*](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/TheAppLifeCycle/TheAppLifeCycle.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH2-SW3).

What you can do though is:

- listen for taps on the button,
- persist the information with the associated timestamp,
- process all the taps you tracked to apply your logic, ie show the daily completion to your user in the UI, etc.

Hope it helps.